# imagemagick create pdf from 2 different images

Tags: imagemagick

I want to create a pdf by imagemagick with 2 different images.

I have command

```
convert -density 1 -size 2255x2255 xc:salmon[100x100] -density 1 image_1.jpg -density 100 image_2.jpeg  -composite test.pdf
```

this is create a pdf but it's combine the both images on same location.

how can change the postion?